# Use a model concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ripping my hair out on this one:

*app/models/concerns/soft_delete.rb:*

```
module SoftDelete
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
        def testing_a_class
             pp "Ima class method"
        end
    end

    def testing_an_instance
        pp "Ima instance method"
    end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include SoftDelete
end
```

*app/models/user.rb:*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    testing_a_class
end
```

Now, in the rails console:

```
x = User.first # I expect "Ima class method" to be printed to the screen
NameError: undefined local variable or method `testing_a_class' for User(no database connection):Class
```

Comment: Why do you reopen `User` in concerns?

Comment: Also, fix your db configuration: `no database connection`

Comment: Looks good besides your structure for user model ```app/models/concerns/user.rb```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev To include the module. I could use the send method, what's best?

Comment: @Starkers: I meant this: http://monosnap.com/image/JTn8CC5BI6ZfTUrUM8QqgE8mIaG1GS.png

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Shoot, sorry about that, edited question

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you saw this idea of including a module in the same file where it's defined, but you must not do it (in rails), because of how rails works (auto-lazy-loading).

Rails doesn't load all classes on startup. Instead when you reference a class that doesn't yet exist, rails attempts to guess where it might be located and loads it from there.

```
x = User.first
```

Before this line, constant `User` does not exist (assuming it wasn't referenced before). When trying to resolve this name, rails will look for file `user.rb` in each of `autoload_paths` (google it up). It will find one at `app/models/user.rb`. Next time you reference `User`, it will just use this constant and will not look it up in the filesystem.

```
# app/models/user.rb:

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    testing_a_class
end
```

The definition that was found contains only an invocation of some unknown method (hence the error). Code in your concern file was not loaded and will never be loaded. To fix this, include the concern in the model file.

```
# app/models/user.rb:

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include SoftDelete

    testing_a_class
end
```

Now it should work.